# Inserting Metatag strings into a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, meta-tags

I want to take meta tags from an external webpage and save it into my mysql db, although I keep getting an error. Some help would be appreciated.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($_POST['url']);

if (array_key_exists("description", $tags)){
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($tags['description']);
}

$postQ = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (userdesc,desc,title,url,userid) VALUES ('$userdesc','$desc','$title','$url','$userid')");
```

The error I keep getting is this:`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,title,url,userid) VALUES ('Wow this house is small','We've featu' at line 1`

Answer (score 3):

`desc` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) either enclose that field name in backticks or rename the field name to something else.

eg.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (userdesc,`desc`,title,url,userid)...
```